# Unable to connect boost library to my project "symbol lookup error"

Tags: c++, boost, linker, java-native-interface, undefined-symbol

I have the following situation:

I've created dynamic library lib.so. This library uses another static library lib.a. Both of them use Boost library (I link them in CMake file). (I use this dynamic library in Java project)

This is code of file.cpp in lib.so, which calls getFilesFromDirectory() from lib.a

```
#include "DrawingDetector.h"
#include "../../DrawingDetection.h"
#include <vector>

#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_DrawingDetector_detectImage( JNIEnv * env, jobject, jstring jMsg)
{
    const char* msg = env->GetStringUTFChars(jMsg,0);
    vector<File> filesPic = getFilesFromDirectory(msg,0);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jMsg, msg);
}
```

This is code of  getFilesFromDirectory() from lib.a:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

#include "DrawingDetection.h"

using namespace std;

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

vector<File> getFilesFromDirectory(string dir, int status)
{
    vector<File> files;
    path directoty = path(dir);
    directory_iterator end;
    if (!exists(directoty))
    {
        cout<<"There is no such directory or file!"<<endl;
}
for (directory_iterator itr(directoty); itr != end; ++itr)
{
     if ( is_regular_file((*itr).path()))
     {
    //some code
     }
}
return files;
 }
```

But when my project invokes lib.so library, it raises the following message:

```
 java: symbol lookup error: /home/orlova/workspace/kmsearch/Images/branches/DrawingDetection/jni/bin/lib.so: undefined symbol:_ZN5boost11filesystem34path21wchar_t_codecvt_facetEv
```

As I found out it crushes in lib.a, when  it tries to invoke boost method "path".
But I declared all boost headers, and linked them in CMake file.
Can you explain, why it doesn't recognize boost methods?

**EDIT**:

The version of my compiler gcc 4.6. And if I use 4.5 everything is fine!

Also if I use some boost methods directly in file.cpp in lib.so everything works fine, for example:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_DrawingDetector_detectImage( JNIEnv * env, jobject, jstring jMsg)
 {
    const char* msg = env->GetStringUTFChars(jMsg,0);
    path directoty = path("/home/orlova");//if I use boost method here
    vector<File> filesPic = getFilesFromDirectory(msg,0);// then everything works fine 
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jMsg, msg);
 }
```

***BUT***

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_DrawingDetector_detectImage( JNIEnv * env, jobject, jstring jMsg)
{
   const char* msg = env->GetStringUTFChars(jMsg,0);
   //path directoty = path("/home/orlova");//if I don't use boost method here
   vector<File> filesPic = getFilesFromDirectory(msg,0);// then this method causes before-mentioned error!! 
   env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jMsg, msg);
```

}

How can you explain this behavior of compiler?

Note, that error occurs in runtime.

***SOLVED***

The problem was in order of libraries in *target_link_libraries* in CMake file.

WRONG:

```
find_library( LIBRARY_MAIN 
        NAMES lib.a
        PATHS ../bin
          )

set ( LIB_JNI     
      jpeg
      ${OpenCV_LIBS}
      ${BOOST_LIB}
      ${LIBRARY_MAIN}//static library is the last in the list of libraries and after boost!
    )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT} ${LIB_JNI} )
```

RIGHT:

```
find_library( LIBRARY_MAIN 
        NAMES lib.a
        PATHS ../bin
          )

set ( LIB_JNI  
      ${LIBRARY_MAIN}
      jpeg
      ${OpenCV_LIBS}
      ${BOOST_LIB}//boost library is the last in the list and after static library!

    )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT} ${LIB_JNI} )
```

Comment: Do you accidentally (or intentionally) link boost *dynamically*?

Comment: Coould you please show Android.mk files for lib.a and for lib.so? Perhaps you've got an incorrect order of static objects you link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you link `Boost.Filesystem` dynamically - if so, you have to ensure that this library gets loaded. You can do this either by adding it to `LOCAL_LDLIBS` line in `Android.mk`, or by pre-loading it manually before you load `lib.so` in Java code.

Alternatively, just link Boost (and everything else) statically to `lib.so` and forget about all this dynamic mess. :)

*UPDATE1*: with regards to the update you posted -- try putting boost_filesystem.a as the *last* object in the linker line.

Comment: I've checked - I link boost libraries statically and boost libraries link succesfully to my project (it founds all paths to libraries "boost library libboost_filesystem.a - found"). I have some new information - I will edit my question.

Comment: I've changed the order of linked libraries and now everything is working! So the order of libraries is very important. Thank you for your advice @Igor R.!! I will edit my question according to your advice)

Comment: @Ann Orlova yes, it's important, please see the following link: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_18.html